# preserve route on error in phoenix create actions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix action that looks like:

```
  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{}, user_params)
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, user} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "#{user.name} created!")
        |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

on validation error, it renders the appropriate form with validation errors, but it does not preserve the appropriate path, eg instead of `/users/new` it displays `/users` since it is trying to `POST` to the resource. It seems like since it should preserve the new route though I understand that we are now in the `create` action. Is there a way to ‘redirect’ and still preserve the changeset? I expect I might need to alter the changeset in the `new` action signature to pass the state to that action, but unsure if this has other consequences I might regret later. My new action:

```
  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = User.changeset(%User{})
    render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
  end
```

Comment: You can just use `ajax` to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such thing in Phoenix. To keep things simple the flow is always one directional. When you enter the url in browser, the `conn` is created and is modified many times, but it can't modify any previous steps.

Redirect just forces the browser to request new url, but it can't carry any parameters with it. It is not a Phoenix thing, but just general HTTP rule.

If you really need the url to have `/new` at the end, you can try one of two hacks:

- less ugly: in `new.html.eex` place some javascript that on page load forcibly sets the url to `users/new`.
- more ugly: break the api and force create action to use `POST /users/new` instead of `POST /users`. I really don't recommend that one, but I mention it just for completeness.